# Symfony 6 / Doctrine - An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I tried to setup my symfony project, everything was well, since I tried to create the doctrine database.
I written my DATABASE_URL in the .env file, that is correct, well I think so, but nothing works, either my local xampp server or my web server.

I get always the same error:

```
[critical] Error thrown while running command "doctrine:database:create". Message: "An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver"


In ExceptionConverter.php line 119:

  An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver


In Exception.php line 30:

  could not find driver


In Driver.php line 28:

  could not find driver
```

Comment: Add the `DATABASE_URL` value that you use to your post.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you may have not enabled the `pdo_mysql` extension in your `php.ini` file.
Try to uncomment the `;extension=pdo_mysql` line inside your `php.ini`.

Beware, your php console may use a different `php.ini` file than the one that runs your application.

Answer (score 5):

I am also a beginner on Symfony and I use ubuntu.

I followed the below steps-

1. I first wrote in my terminal the command: `symfony check:requirements` to know what was wrong.
2. I got confirmation that my `pdo_mysql` had missing drivers and as I'm using php 8.2, so I installed `MySQL` for `php8.2`.
3. In the terminal, type the command `sudo apt-get install -y php8.2-mysql`
   and then retype the command: `php bin/console doctrine:database:create` for the creation of the database.

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

New to symfony, I also had this problem.

I needed to get an `.env.local` file from another developer, and I did not realize that the `.env.local` file needed to go in to the `app/` directory.

So that the `app/.env` and `app/.env.local` are both in place.

It was only then that symfony was able to pick up the correct `DATABASE_URL`